# MS Chart - Get y value of a serie with DateTime value for x-axis with mouse position

Tags: c#, mschart, mouse-cursor

Let's see if there is anyone who can help me :)

1. I need to get the y value of a line tipe Serie just with the mouse coords.  I want to do this without having to put the mouse over the line bust moving the mouse horizontaly across the ChartArea.

I've read a lot of examples and other questions here but most of them just get the y value of the  mouse position rather than the y value of the serie.  I tried to get the y value of the series with the x-value using the findbyvalue method, but the method always returns null value because my x-axis is a double value converted from a DateTime variable and it's impossible to get the same x value because there are lots of decimals.

2. Another thing I tried was to get something like this

[image]

But all the examples i've seen converts the mouse coordinates and use them to set the cursor position. And even when I try to do this I can't get the x cursor to show because when I set a double value to the x cursor position like "412346,23452345", it only gets the integer part "412346.0".

I would appreciate any help on the topic.

Thank you!